# Why Windows desktop 10 tablet cannot open NFC reader tags page?

Tags: nfc, windows-10-universal, ionic3

I did an Ionic App for Windows desktop 10 tablet. It consists two pages, main to read DB and click on the button to read NFC page.

When I build the app the got the error below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc
npm install --save @ionic-native/nfc
```

you need to add it to the `providers` array of you App's module (`app.module.ts`):

```
...

import { NFC } from '@ionic-native/nfc';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    NFC,  // <----- like this!
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks, I give a try and let see. Also, I added `Ndef` to provider and import it.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: the error message show other small thing, which is `error response with status: 0 for URL: null`. Why do you think this problem?. The API configured as a cross origin.